# Ellipse 3-partition: same area and perimeter

Tags: geometry, integer-partitions

Inspired by the question,
"[How to partition area of an ellipse into odd number of regions?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55986/),"
I ask for a partition an ellipse into three convex pieces, 
each of which has the same area
and the same perimeter.  The perimeter includes both arcs of the ellipse and whatever
cuts are used.

This is known to be possible by recent results of Aronov and Hubbard, "[Convex Equipartitions of volume and surface area](http://arxiv.org/abs/1010.4611)," 
and by Karasev, "[Equipartition of several measures](http://arxiv.org/abs/1011.4762v2),"
but perhaps the general techniques in these papers
(which I have not studied)
need not be used in this special case.
Perhaps there is a natural construction?

**Update.** The two papers I cited above are both difficult for me to penetrate.
The special case of equipartition into three parts was achieved earlier in a paper by
Imre Bárány, Pavle Blagojevićc, and András Szűcsd,
"[Equipartitioning by a convex 3-fan](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S000187080900262X)," which I cannot access at the moment.
But as you can infer from the title, the partition is accomplished via a convex 3-fan:
a point with three rays emanating from that point.

Comment: Going by the linked papers, I assume you want the three pieces to be *convex* as well? If so, you may want to mention that in the question; otherwise there are some pretty simple constructions that work.

Comment: Thank you, Rahul! Corrected.

Comment: One possibility at least worth a try is three outward rays from the origin given by angles $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$. The areas can be found with $\frac{1}{2}\int r^2d\theta$ and the perimeters using elliptic integrals of the second kind.

Comment: @Peter: I had the pleasure of attending a talk by Steiger on this nice result :-)  Good idea, to use the uniqueness of the 6-partition!  That would reduce to search to just one variable, a point on $S^1$.

Comment: @anon: If the first ray is at angle $\theta$, then the area constraint fixes the other two angles.  By a continuity argument, there will be angles for which the first two perimeters match, but you would need to be lucky for the third perimeter to match as well.  To adjust your luckiness, starting from $(x,0)$ instead of the origin may give you the flexibility you need.

Comment: Hmm, why can't we just 3-partition a circle and project that figure onto a non-orthogonal plane... oh. Because by age 20 we had learned to compute arc length and it doesn't work that way.

Comment: If you want convex pieces, I think you cannot do much else then paritition by a fan with straight lines, or else possibly cut up the ellipse by two non-intersecting straight lines. If the boundary between two pieces has nonzero curvature (and I think even more so if it is not smooth) then one of the two separated pieces will fail to be convex.

Comment: I just deleted an "answer" in which I forgot to include the ray lengths in the perimeter definitions. THis problem is more difficult than I thought by far, and I now don't think it's easy to do if we select a point on the major axis of the ellipse at which to center the fan. At least it doesn't sweem to be a case of the one variable mean value theorem...

Answer (score 2):

Let $V_1 V_2$ be the major axis of our ellipse, with area $\Delta$. 
Take a point $P$ between $V_1$ and $V_2$ such that $PV_1=x$, and two points $Q_1,Q_2$ such that $Q_1 Q_2$ is perpendicular to $V_1 V_2$ and the elliptic sector $E_1$ delimited by the rays $PQ_1,PQ_2$ has area $\Delta/3$. 
Let $E_2$ be the elliptic sector delimited by the rays $PQ_1,PV_2$ and $p_j(x)$ the perimeter of $E_j$. The function

$$ f(x) = p_1(x) - p_2(x) $$

is clearly continous, so, if we find two points $x_0,y_0$ such that $f(x_0)f(y_0)<0$, we are sure that $f$ has at least a zero $z$ and we have done, since:

$$ \Delta(E_2) = \frac{\Delta-\Delta(E_1)}{2} = \Delta(E_1). $$

Comment: However, to ensure the convexity of $E_1$ we must have $x\geq 0.367534\dots V_1V_2$.