# What is the hatched area of ​​an ellipse?

Tags: geometry

ellipse described about the circle in which a regular pentagon is constructed mapped on an ellipse[image]

[image]

The surface can be calculated from my formula

$A=\frac{a.b.\pi.\alpha}{360}$

Total area will be an ellipse

[image]

Area n work will be

$An=\frac{b.\sin\alpha.a \cos\alpha}{2}+\frac{b.\sin\alpha.a(1-\cos\alpha)}{2} $

$An=\frac{a.b}{2}(\sin\alpha\cos\alpha+\sin\alpha-\sin\alpha\cos\alpha) $

$An=\frac{a.b}{2}\sin\alpha=\frac{a.b}{2}\sin(\frac{360}{n}) $

How is this n part of it multiplied by n

$  A=a.b.\pi $

$ \frac{n}{2}\sin(\frac{360}{n})$ [look](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/44631/how-do-you-find-the-formula-for-an-area-of-the-circle-through-integration/56539#56539)

Answer (score 5):

It is $\frac{1}{5}$ of the area of the ellipse, which is $\frac{\pi}{5}ab$.  The mapping from the circle to the ellipse by scaling along the $y$-axis maps the points from the pentagon, to the points on the ellipse.  This mapping preserves relative areas, and since the pentagon divides the circle into $5$ equal sectors, the mapped points divide the ellipse into $5$ equal sectors.

Comment: True to the method in the division area of ​​ellipse

Answer (score 2):

The above is exactly the method suggested in one of the answers to your [earlier question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55986/how-to-partition-area-of-an-ellipse-into-odd-number-of-regions) about dividing an ellipse into an odd number of parts.  But the picture certainly improves the presentation.

Comment: Sorry, I'd not seen the earlier question.  I will peruse posters' recent questions more carefully.

Answer (score 1):

The area of an ellipse sector from $0$ to $\theta$ degrees is $a b \theta/2$. The angle $\theta$ is measured along the circle with radius $a$. If a regular n-gon in inscribed into this circle then the angle of one sector is $\theta = 2\pi/n$. Hence, the area of an ellipse sector corresponding to one n-gon sector is $\pi a b / n$, for a pentagon $\pi a b / 5$.