# Getting the angle that is needed for covering a given distance on an ellipse's cirumference

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

In a small programming exercise I asked myself, I want to calculate various things about ellipses. The part I'm stuck with is the following: I want to calculate the angle that is needed cor covering a given distance on the circumference of a given ellipse, while starting on a given angle. This image should illustrate the problem:

[image]

It is guaranteed that α < 90°, but it is possible that α+β > 90°

I would like to do this only with mathematical operations that are available in 'general' programming languages (like C++, e.g. those in [`cmath`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_mathematical_functions)). So, while calculating the actual result in my program, I would like to avoid integrals or derivatives. Although the result will probably less exact without these operations, it should have maximum deviation of ~5%.

Comment: So (to make sure I understand what you're asking for), you would like a formula that may be approximate, but is at least closed-form, so that it does not require numerical integration, and should have an error no more than $1/20$ of the actual value of $\beta$?

Comment: you must specify the starting angle also..

Comment: For the exact solution, you'd need [elliptic integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral) or rather [their inverse](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1123360/35416). See also [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/172766/35416) dealing with a related problem of turning arc length into something that is easier to handle. I think for this 5% limit to make sense you'll have to speficy some limit on the eccentricity of the ellipse.

Comment: @BrianTung That's right.

Comment: @Narasimham $\alpha$ is the given starting angle.

Comment: How is $c$ given? Just as a numerical value?

Comment: @NaCl Yes, it is.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to find for given arc distance on a given ellipse between a point whose polar coordinates are $(\alpha, r_\alpha) $ , extra  $\beta $  needed,  right? There are two possibilities..

Please look up standard derivation of ellipse arc length derivation in terms elliptic integrals ( iirc, $E(\epsilon)\, 2 \pi a $, of second kind) in terms of eccentricity $ \epsilon $ or a/b. It will be easy to find because that is how elliptic integrals originally arose.

Next, you need the polar coordinate form for a central ellipse:

$$\frac{1}{r^2} =\frac{\cos ^2\theta }{a^2} + \frac{\sin ^2\theta}{b^2}. $$

Comment: The two points you mentioned are right, but the arc distance between these points ($c$ in my image) is _given_, I want to get the angle $\beta$ that is needed for covering this distance.