# Get coordinates of function based on arc length

Tags: numerical-methods, elliptic-integrals, arc-length

Given a function (e.g. $f(x) = \sin(x)$) and an arc length value, I want to calculate the corresponding $x$-value to calculate the coordinates of the point, which is located on the function with the specific arc length.

Is there a possibility to do that with any function or can I just do this for specific functions?

Since the goal is to create a script/program which does this for me, a numeric solution would be good enough.

Thanks for you help!

Comment: Are you looking for the positive $x$-coordinate corresponding to the arc length from $x=0$? If something else, you need to specify.

Comment: A more direct example: Image you are walking on a sine-wave path. After 10 meters walking on the path, you want to know at which coordinates you are standing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For *any* continuous function $f(x)$, the arc length from $x=0$ to $x=a$ is given by
$$L(a)=\int_0^a\sqrt{1+(f'(x))^2}\ dx$$
You are happy with a numerical solution for $a=a^*$ given $L(a)=L^*$. Here is a simple (albeit rather inefficient) method that proceeds this way:

- Start with two guesses for the desired x-coordinate $a^*$, $a_0$ and $a_1$, such that $L(a_0)<L^*$ and $L(a_1)>L^*$. (Evaluating the integral that yields $L(a)$ is *itself* almost always done numerically.) These two guesses form an interval bracketing $a^*$.
- Look at the midpoint of this interval $a_m$ and calculate $L(a_m)$. If this is less than $L^*$, replace $a_0$ with $a_m$; if greater, replace $a_1$ with $a_m$.
- Repeat the last step until the desired precision is reached, at which point $a^*$ can be taken as the average of the interval endpoints. Compute $f(a^*)$ and you are done.

Answer (score 1):

Integrating the arc length numerically is a possibility but is inconvenient as you have no control on the value of the arc length that you reach. It will return $s(x)$ for values of $x$ with a fixed increment, but you still have to invert the relation to get $x$ as a function of $s$, by interpolation.

A better way is to consider the differential equation

$$\frac{dx}{ds}=\frac1{\sqrt{1+f'^2(x)}}$$ and integrate it by your favorite method, such as Runge-Kutta. Then you can reach the values of $s$ that you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you travel along the graph of $f(x)=\sin(x)$ by starting at the origin, the distance travelled when you reach $(x,\sin x)$ is given by:
$$ L(x)=\int_{0}^{x}\sqrt{1+\cos^2(t)}\,dt $$
that is an [elliptic integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral). Your problem is so equivalent to inverting an elliptic integral: that can be done in terms of [Jacobi elliptic functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_elliptic_functions). In general it is not an easy task, and it is better to exploit Newton's method, as suggested [in this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1640946/44121) to a similar question.