# Arc length to $x$ of a hyperbola?

Tags: calculus, hyperbolic-functions, inverse-function, elementary-functions, arc-length

I want to find the relationship between arc length $A$ of a hyperbolic function and it's corresponding horizontal location $a$ relative to the $y$ axis. In this case: the arc length is the input and $a$ is the output.

To find the arc length $A$ of a function $f$ between $x=0$ and $a$, one uses the formula:

$$A(a)=\int_0^a\sqrt{1+(\frac{d}{dx}f(x))^2}dx$$

Though, when calculating it for a hyperbolic function $\sqrt{x^2-1}$, the integral is non-elementary.

$$A(a)=\int_0^a\sqrt{1+\frac{x^2}{x^2-1}}dx$$

Yet I still want to find the inverse relationship between $A$ and $a$ (closed form or not).
i.e:
$$a(A)=?$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you will have to start measuring from somewhere other than $x=0$ because the hyperbola does not reach $x=0$.  It only covers $(-\infty,-1]\cup[1,\infty)$.  It would be a little cleaner to regard $x$ as a function of $y$.  The positive branch goes through $(1,0)$ and has a horizontal instead of vertical slope at the point $(1,0)$.  Now the function is $x=\sqrt{1+y^2}$ Your arc length becomes $\int_0^a \sqrt{1+\frac {y^2}{y^2+1}}dy$ which [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%20sqrt((2y%5E2%2B1)%2F(y%5E2%2B1))) can do using an elliptic integral of a hyperbolic sine.

Comment: Ah right forgot about that, in that case I assume starting from $x=1$ would be the cleanest.

Comment: The vertical slope of the curve at $x=1$ puts a zero in the denominator and makes your integral improper.  That is why I suggested $x=f(y)$.  The other integral can be done, but also involves elliptic functions.

Comment: Ah, another touche.

Answer (score 1):

For a two sheet parabola, the integral simplifies down to $\int \sqrt{1+tanh^2(u)} du$, which Wolfram Alpha can solve, the answer being equivalent to the elliptic integral, but no imaginary numbers are needed and its all just hyperbolic trig functions and constants.

Comment: Please don't reference WolframAlpha in the answer - try to make it self-contained.

Answer (score 1):

$\def\E{\operatorname E}\def\I{\operatorname I} \def\L{\operatorname L} \def\sgn{\operatorname{sgn}}$
Here is a closed form from

> [Inverse of elliptic integral of the second kind](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1123360/inverse-of-elliptic-integral-of-second-kind)

using [$\E(x,m),m=k^2$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=EllipticE%28x%2Cm%29), [regularized incomplete beta $\I_z(a,b)$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=-i+%28second+leminscate+constant+%29betaregularized%28sin%282+i+asinh%28x%29%29%5E2%2C1%2F2%2C3%2F4%29+vs+-i+EllipticE%28i+asinh%28x%29%2C2%29) function, and [second Lemniscate $\L_2$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=second+lemniscate+constant) constant:

$$A(a)=\int_0^a \sqrt{\frac{x^2}{x^2+1}+1}dx=-i\E(i\sinh^{-1}(a),2)=-i\sgn(x)\L_2\I_{-\sinh^2(2\sinh^{-1}(a))}\left(\frac12,\frac34\right)$$

Unfortunately, [inverse beta regularized $\I^{-1}_s(a,b)$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=inverse+beta+regularized) only solves $A(a)=z,\text{Re}(z)=0$:

$$a(A)=\pm i\sin\left(\frac12\sin^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\I^{-1}_{\mp\frac{i A}{\L_2}}\left(\frac12,\frac34\right)}\right)\right)=\pm\frac i2\left(\sqrt{1-\sqrt{\I^{-1}_{\mp\frac{i A}{\L_2}}\left(\frac12,\frac34\right)}}-\sqrt{\sqrt{\I^{-1}_{\mp\frac{i A}{\L_2}}\left(\frac12,\frac34\right)}+1}\right),0\le iA\le\L_2$$

[**shown here**](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot+-i+w-i+EllipticE%28i+asinh%28i+sin%280.5+sin%5E%28-1%29%28sqrt%28InverseBetaRegularized%28-i%28i+w%29%2F%28second+lemniscate+constant%29%2C+0.5%2C+0.75%29%29%29%29%29%2C2%29+from+0+to+1) where one of each sign is taken. The plot in the link gives a very small error, but it is a computation limitation. Plot of $a(i w),|w|\le\L_2:$

[image]