# Inversion of the imcomplete elliptic integral of 2nd kind: $E(z|m)=x\;\Longleftrightarrow\; z=\text{bm}(x|m)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion, inverse, inverse-function, elliptic-functions

I would like an opinion on this issue: similarly to the fact that
$$F(z|m)=x\Longleftrightarrow z=\text{am}(x|m)$$

I also tried to reverse the function $E(z|m)$ and got the following series (I arbitrarily called $\text{bm}(x|m)$ the inverse)

$$E(z|m)=x\Longleftrightarrow z=\text{bm}(x|m)$$

---

$$\text{bm}(x|m)\propto x+\frac{mx^{3}}{3!}+\frac{m(13m^{2}-4)}{5!}x^{5}+\frac{m(493m^{2}-284m+16)}{7!}x^{7}+\frac{m(37369m^{3}-31224m^{2}+4944m-64)}{9!}x^{9}+\tfrac{m(4732249m^{4}-5165224m^{3}+1406832m^{2}-81088m+256)}{11!}x^{11}+\tfrac{m(901188997m^{5}-1212651548m^{4}+474297712m^{3}-56084992m^{2}+1306880m-1024)}{13!}x^{13}+\tfrac{m(240798388357m^{6}-384956066148m^{5}+197165292576m^{4}-36844921856m^{3}+2119725312m^{2}-20954112m+4096)}{15!}x^{15}+\;...$$
For $|x|<\dfrac{\pi}{2}$

I can't see useful recurring patterns to search the closed formula, does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: You may find https://oeis.org/A281181 sequence of interest. The numbers corresp;ond to the leading term coefficient of the numerators.

Comment: Maybe a differential equation for “bm” and [recurrence relation for the coefficients](http://www.homepages.ucl.ac.uk/~ucahwts/lgsnotes/EJAM_Quantiles.pdf) would work. Also, this question may be a duplicate of [inversion of elliptic integral of the second kind](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1123360/inverse-of-elliptic-integral-of-second-kind?rq=1)

Comment: What happened to the answer saying “ If this is for numerical calculations, for small $z$, a good approximation of $E(z|m) $ is obtained”

Comment: @ТymaGaidash٠ I can imagine that whoever wrote it deleted it for some reason (maybe there was some mistake or I don't know)