# Midpoint of a quarter-ellipse

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

Consider an ellipse described by the equation $ \frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1 $. Is there a closed form expression for the midpoint of the arc which goes from $ (a,0) $ to $ (0,b) $ ?

Comment: Midpoint in the sense of dividing the *arclength* in half?

Comment: no, there is not

Comment: Isn't it $1/8$ of the [Circumference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse#Circumference)?

Comment: On the other hand, there IS an explicit formula for finding the point $(x', y')$ that is twice as far along the ellipse as some point $(x, y)$, a kind of elliptical double-angle formula, due to Fagnano. See https://books.google.com/books?id=oxH2CAAAQBAJ&pg=PA181&lpg=PA181&dq=doubling+arc+length+on+an+ellipse&source=bl&ots=Ea2LrLT2f9&sig=sRplsNYyYrz7FbM8B4DSgrXNHpA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjV9qG6rKXVAhWixlQKHVxiBl0Q6AEITTAG#v=onepage&q=doubling%20arc%20length%20on%20an%20ellipse&f=false

Comment: @John: yes, in that sense.

Comment: @MVL It involves finding $\phi$ from  second elliptic integral $ E(e^2, \phi) $

Comment: Related to [Calculating equidistant points around an ellipse arc](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/172766/35416), for the special case of 8 equidistant points, including the vertices. Linked posts there might be useful reading, too.